# Cppcheck integration with Keil

Tags: keil, cppcheck

I want to test C code from my actual Keil project. I followed the instructions from [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sw9xhxsyRtw). I manageed to set it up, but when I start `cppcheck` it says:

> cppcheck: error: could not find or open any of the paths given.

No matter which path I give it's always like that. From the other side, if I try to check files directly from `cppcheck` and select the same path I get information with no issue. Maybe I'm missing something here?

Keil version: 5.24.2.0
`cppcheck` version: 2.0
OS: Windows 10